# Bot sends message twice

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just figured out how to check reactions in discord.py, but now I have another issue. The bot sends both messages for both reactions when just one reaction happens.

```
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def offer(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="<a:Loading:768095883664424971> Incoming Offer", value=f"The <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> have offered {member.mention}.")

    offer_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>")
    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:XMark:768095331555606528>")
    await member.send("You have been offered to the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>. You have 30 minutes to accept/decline.")

    channel = ctx.channel

    def check(reaction, member):
        return member == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>'

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=1800.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await channel.send(f"{member.mention} hasn't reacted in time.")
    else:
         await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, {member.mention} has accepted <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> offer.")
         
    def check(reaction, member):
        return member == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '<a:XMark:768095331555606528>'

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=1800.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await channel.send(f"{member.mention} hasn't reacted in time.")
    else:
        await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, {member.mention} has declined <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> offer.")

    await asyncio.sleep(1800)
    await offer_sent.delete()
```

I just recently added this to my code in order to check both reactions, but can't figure out the problem.

Comment: I tested the code and was unable to reproduce the problem. Try what LaughlanMcG said and if that doesn't work consider adding more detail.

Comment: Check if you are running the code more than once, you'll have to close the other versions. If that wasn't the problem, it might be because you are using the `on_message()` event. It's possible that `process_commands()` is being called more than once.

Comment: Oh alright, well when I tested, I found that it only sends both if they react to both. Is there a way to end the command as soon as there's a reaction?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code that should send the message twice, you may be running two version of the code. Open task manager and kill any unwanted python processes or just restart your computer

Comment: Well, I'm running the bot in repl.it. There are 12 different files for the code because I'm making the bot with an emoji prefix per team. I know I would be able to put it all in one, but I have it separate for more customization. Would this affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you ran the program twice, to make sure this doesn't happen, I suggest implementing a kill switch so every time when you rerun the program you activate the kill switch first on Discord then run the program again. An example of the killswitch that I made is something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def quit(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Shutting down the bot")
    return await client.logout() # this just shuts down the bot.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem once, and the main cause was: Heroku.
If you are hosting your bot on somewhere else, maybe you should change their prefixes so you don't trigger them both!

Comment: Well, I am hosting it in different places, but I do have the prefix changed. It only sends messages twice on the command requiring reactions. I'm not sure if I can have a killswitch after the first reaction is detected, so let me know if I can @Phan Nhật Huy